# "patterns in switch statements are a preview feature and are disabled by default" when switching to java 17 - what is the right solution?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, switch-statement, java-17

I am working on moving some projects from java 11 to java 17 and from Spring Boot 2.7.8 to Spring Boot 3.0.0.

I have the following method in a test class:

```
    protected void stub(HttpMethod method, String url, ResponseDefinitionBuilder response) {
        switch (method) {
            case GET:
                wireMockServer.stubFor(get(urlMatching(url)).willReturn(response));
                break;
            case POST:
                wireMockServer.stubFor(post(urlMatching(url)).willReturn(response));
                break;
            case PUT:
                wireMockServer.stubFor(put(urlMatching(url)).willReturn(response));
                break;
            case DELETE:
                wireMockServer.stubFor(delete(urlMatching(url)).willReturn(response));
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("invalid http method");
        }
    }
```

when working with java 11, but when I switched to java 17 and in the pom.xml the following was specified:

```
 <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
```

and

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

The code stopped working with the following error:

```
patterns in switch statements are a preview feature and are disabled by default.
```

Obviously it interferes with the pattern matching preview feature in java 17.

What is the right solution for this?

Comment: Since the syntax of your code hasn’t changed, you should check whether `HttpMethod` still resolves to an `enum` type in the new environment.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't resolve in spring-web 6.0.2 So what is the solution in this case?

Comment: First of all, you should include in your question that you updated the Spring Web version. Then, if the framework authors had the glorious idea to change an `enum` type to a non-`enum` type, you can’t `switch` over it anymore. Use `if … else` or a `Map` from object to handler or such alike. Or switch over its `name()` string.

Comment: @Holger such breaking changes are allowed in major releases of Spring, like in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The type `HttpMethod` has been changed from [an `enum` type](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework/spring-web/5.3.11/org/springframework/http/HttpMethod.html) to a [non-`enum` type](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpMethod.html). Therefore, you can’t `switch` over it anymore. The error message is confusing, because you can switch over non-`enum` types with pattern matching, so the compiler assumes that you’re trying that.

An alternative is to switch over the string representation instead. This is also an opportunity to clean up this code:

```java
protected void stub(HttpMethod method, String url, ResponseDefinitionBuilder response) {
    var um = urlMatching(url);
    var processed = switch(method.name()) {
        case "GET" -> get(um);
        case "POST" -> post(um);
        case "PUT" -> put(um);
        case "DELETE" -> delete(um);
        default -> throw new RuntimeException("invalid or unsupported http method");
    };
    wireMockServer.stubFor(processed.willReturn(response));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this plugin entry in your Maven project in `pom.xml`:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        .....
        .....
        .....
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>17</release> <!-- <release>13/14/15</release> ->
                <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please make sure to read your answer after posting to make sure it appears as you intended.  Your answer was pretty much unreadable, since XML/HTML tags aren't displayed when they aren't included in a code-block.  Check out [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](/help/formatting) and  the [Markdown help](/editing-help) for assistance.  Thanks!